# How to programmatically set TextField value?

Tags: reactjs, material-design-lite

The following code discovers the `value` prop of the `Textfield` does not get updated programmatically. The `clear()` function should reset the value of the `Textfiled` to empty string. Am I doing anything wrong?

```js
render(
  <div>
    <IconButton name="clear" className="blue" onClick={() => this.clear()}/>
    <Textfield
            onKeyUp={(e) => this.onKeyUp(e)}
            label="Search Address, city, zip"
            expandable
            expandableIcon="search"
            floatingLabel
            value={this.state.searchText} />
 </div>)

onKeyUp(e) {
    const term = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      searchText: term
    })
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
     // do stuff
    }
  }

clear() {
    this.setState({
      searchText: ''
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, due to I havent got enought rep to comment.

Im not familiar with material-design-lite, I have some experience using material-ui. Textfield component in material-ui did only contain onChange method. Are you sure the library you are using supports onKeyUp function ?

*Edit: Found you had posted an issue on github in React-mdl. 
I have searched through the src files and found TextField.js, this component does not support onKeyUp. You can however use onChange.

This should work:

```
render(
  <div>
    <IconButton name="clear" className="blue" onClick={() => this.clear()}/>
    <Textfield
            onChange={(e) => this.onKeyUp(e)}
            label="Search Address, city, zip"
            expandable
            expandableIcon="search"
            floatingLabel
            value={this.state.searchText} />
 </div>)
```

https://github.com/react-mdl/react-mdl/blob/master/src/Textfield.js

Comment: could you link the component library you are using ?